# JS: Reverse an Array but Reverse the Original Array Only --> Error: running with no output

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, arguments, reverse

I have following problem:

// Reverse Array

Write a function that accepts an array and reverses that array in place. The behavior should mimic the behavior of the native .reverse() array method. However, your reverse function should accept the array to operate on as an argument, rather than being invoked as a method on that array.

Do not use the native .reverse() method in your own implementation.

I tried the following code:

```
let myArray = [1, 2, 3, 4];


function reverse(myArray) {

  let newArray = []; 

  // pop all of elements from roginal array, and store in new array

  for (i=myArray.length-1; i>=0; i--){
    newArray.push(myArray[i])

    console.log(newArray)
  }

  while (newArray.length){

    myArray.unshift(newArray)
  }


  return myArray; 
}


reverse(myArray);
console.log(myArray) // expected output is [4, 3, 2, 1]
```

My code just keeps running and no console.log output is produced.  Notice I want the reverse done to the input array argument.

What am I doing wrong? Also, what does while (newArray.length) mean / what is it doing conceptually?

Comment: You've missed an important part of the requirement: _"...and reverses that array **in place**"_

Comment: and the reason you code "just keeps running" is your infinite loop - nothing inside that loop `while (newArray.length)` changes the length of `newArray`

Comment: To reverse an array _in place_ you just swap the first and last element, and then the second and second-to-last element, etc, stopping when you get half way.

Comment: I would also suggest swapping. Swap the i th element with length-i element.

Comment: You have selected an answer that will cause you to fail your assignment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why you need the `unshift` you can just iterate and return the array where you are pushing the value

```js
let myArray = [1, 2, 3, 4];

function reverse(myArray) {
  let newArray = [];
  for (i = myArray.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    newArray.push(myArray[i])
  }
  return newArray;
}
console.log(reverse(myArray))
```

Comment: This is *not* an in-place reversal!

Answer (score 0):

Just swap pairs starting at either end of the array, until there's none left:

```
function reverse(a) {
    for (let i = 0, j = a.length - 1; i < j; ++i, --j) {
        let tmp = a[i];
        a[i] = a[j];
        a[j] = tmp;
    }
    return a;  // not required, but allows use in an expression
}
```

In ES2016 you can use destructuring assignments to perform the swap in one operation without the use of a temporary variable:

```
function reverse(a) {
    for (let i = 0, j = a.length - 1; i < j; ++i, --j) {
        [ a[j], a[i] ] = [ a[i], a[j] ];
    }
    return a;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can swap first and last element in an array and iteratively swap the next and prev respectively.

You don't have to visit the complete set in the loop, get the middle element and rotate the index around that

```js
function reverseInArray(arr){
  let len = arr.length;
  let temp;
  for(let i=0; i < len/2; i++){
   temp = arr[i];
    arr[i] = arr[len - i - 1];
    arr[len - i - 1] = temp;
  }  
  return arr;
}

console.log(reverseInArray([1,2,3,4,5]));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate the array 'till the middle, and switch between the current (`i`) and the opposite (`length - i - 1`):

```js
const myArray = [1, 2, 3, 4];

function reverse(myArray) {
  const length = myArray.length;
  const middle = Math.floor(length / 2);
  
  for(let i = 0; i < middle; i++) {
    let tmp = myArray[i];
    myArray[i] = myArray[length - i - 1];
    myArray[length - i - 1] = tmp;
  }
}


reverse(myArray);
console.log(myArray) // expected output is [4, 3, 2, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could swap the first and the last element and start from the most inner item.

```js
function reverse(array) {
    var i = array.length >> 1, // take half of the length as integer
        l = array.length - 1;  // last index value to calculate the other side

    while (i--) [array[i], array[l - i]] = [array[l - i], array[i]];
}

var a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];

reverse(a);
console.log(...a);
```

Comment: interesting use of structured assignment to achieve the element swap :)

Answer (score -1):

Here:

```
  while (newArray.length){

    myArray.unshift(newArray)
  }
```

You're adding to `myArray`, but not taking from `newArray`, hence infinite loop. Methinks it should be `myArray.unshift(newArray.pop())`.